# transient objects in session

Tags: java, session, transient

I have read in one of framework documentation, "If large objects are be required in the session, the application should define these as transient objects in the Session Manager"

How does defining those large object transient will make no impact on keeping large objects in session?

Comment: what session? hibernate session?

Comment: You should provide the link where you read that.

Answer (score 2):

The session objects are persisted by the web container session manager. If you store large objects in the session, then it will take more time to write those objects. If you make those objects as transient they will not be considered when the HttpSession object is serialized by the container.This reduces the time it takes to write the object out and also the space occupied in the database if one is used.

Comment: yer only the advantage is having trasient is at the time we persist the object in session know. Other wise make it trasient have no impact on storing those objects in session for purpose like transport the data with in application